# Renaming with lists

Tags: bash, for-loop, rename

I have a set of files that I would like to rename by using new filenames stored in a `txt` file. My original files:

```
7170M
7172M
7187P
7192N
7198P
```

I would like to add to each filename specific new names so that the above files become:

```
1956_26_7170M
1962_12_7172M
1989_32_7187P
1986_22_7192N
1943_13_7198P
```

I created a document `new_names.txt` containing new filenames and tried the following.

```
for f in *.txt; do mv "$f" "$new_name"; done < new_names.txt
```

But it changes only the first filename.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only store the new parts of the names in the file (provided you'll process the files in the sorted order):

```
1956_26
1962_12
1989_32
1986_22
1943_13
```

Then, iterate over the files, read one line for each of them:

```
for file in 7* ; do
    read new
    mv "$file" "$new"_"$file"
done < new_names.txt
```

Your main problem was than `for ... in` doesn't read from a file, it iterates over a list given after `in`. In your case, the list only had one member: `new_names.txt`. Also, You didn't populate $new_name anywhere.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion and explanation of where I made a mistake.